# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 code changes not being picked up

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I'm experiencing some very strange behaviour using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

My code changes don't seem to be picked up and step-through thinks that I'm trying to step through a different version of the source code.

I have tried the following:

- Solution clean & rebuild
- Delete dll's in the bin folder, clean, rebuild
- Restart Visual Studio 2013
- Reboot machine

By doing the above I'm not getting the out-of-date source code error but when I'm stepping through the code it's not picking up the change.

I have checked the build configuration manager and everything in the build column is checked and it's set to run in debug mode for any cpu.

Has anyone been experiencing similar issues?  If so, have you found a resolution or workaround to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging, open Debug -> Windows -> Modules, choose the module you're interested and select 'Symbol Load Information' from context menu. It will give you some hints why latest code is not picked up.

Comment: Not quite sure what was causing is, changed the assembly version number and worked.  Saw in the modules it picked it up and all was fine...bizarre...and confusing of why it was doing this

Comment: @anD666 changing the assembly version fixed it for me too, thanks!